# What is the best way to store config settings in Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, application-settings

I have a python based google app engine webserver. I would like to save certain configs such that the config changes shouldn't warrant a server restart. For example, my web-server makes an http request to another server and I would like to store the host:port of the secondary server as a config setting.

I was thinking about using the database table for this. Are there other alternatives such as environment variable etc?

Comment: Maybe this one helps http://stackoverflow.com/q/21393107/1741542

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a DB table to store the configs as suggested in [Python and YAML- GAE app settings file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21393107/1741542)

```
class Config(db.Model):
    """
    Application Config
    """   

    name  = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    value = db.StringProperty(required=True)

    @staticmethod
    def create_config(name,
                      value):
        pass
```